# cocoa: what's the different of CATransaction and NSAnimationContext

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

I can animately move a layer-hosing view using code:

```
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:2];
self.imageLayer.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
```

and I can do it by following code as well:

```
 [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
    [context setDuration:2];
    self.imageLayer.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
} completionHandler:nil];
```

I want to know what's the difference between CATransaction and NSAnimationContext, which one I should use to animate view? why can I set the duration in NSAnimationContext and CATransaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CATransaction works on Core Animation layer animations. CATransaction is cross-platform between iOS and Mac OS.

NSAnimationContext works with an NSAnimationContext. It's Mac OS specific.

(The NS animation stuff is Mac-only, and the UIView animation stuff is iOS only.)

I work in iOS more than Mac OS these days, and I always look for cross-platform ways to do things.

CAAnimation, CALayer, CAAnimationGroup, etc, are nearly identical between Mac and iOS. There are some differences (e.g. quicktime layers are not supported in iOS, Core Image support is more limited in iOS, etc.) but CA stuff is more alike than different.

Answer (score 4):

For the most part `NSAnimationContext` is implemented as a wrapper around `CATransaction`. You can use a disassembler tool like [Hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com) to reverse-engineer AppKit's code and see this yourself. Here are some of the `NSAnimationContext`'s reconstructed methods in pseudo-Objective-C:

```
void +[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping](void * self, void * _cmd) {
  if (([CATransaction currentState] & 0x3) != 0x0) {
    [CATransaction begin];
  } else {
    rdi = @class(CATransaction);
    if (pthread_main_np() != 0x0) {
      [rdi activate];
      [CATransaction begin];
    }
    else {
      [rdi begin];
      [CATransaction activateBackground:0x1];
    }
  }
  [CATransaction setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"NSAnimationContextBeganGroup"];
  return;
}

void +[NSAnimationContext endGrouping](void * self, void * _cmd) {
  [CATransaction commit];
  return;
}

void -[NSAnimationContext setTimingFunction:](void * self, void * _cmd, void * arg2) {
  [CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:arg2];
  return;
}
```

Besides this `NSAnimationContext` has a couple of additional features like altering animation duration if shift key is down (`NSAnimationSlowMotionOnShift`) and measuring performance.