# How to update my constraints with animation without losing children constraints on the parent?

Tags: swift, cocoa, constraints

I have a blueView as a parent that has for own a custom constraint and this blueView has a subView called redView, the constraint of redView is always same like in the code, but the constraint of blueView is going updated after lunching app in 2 sec.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
        let blueView: NSView = NSView()
        blueView.wantsLayer = true
        blueView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor

        self.view.addSubview(blueView)
        
        
        blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        blueView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 50.0).isActive = true
        blueView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 50.0).isActive = true
        blueView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
        blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
        

        let redView: NSView = NSView()
        redView.wantsLayer = true
        redView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
        

        blueView.addSubview(redView)
        redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        redView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        redView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        redView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
        redView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true


        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(2)) {
            
            blueView.removeConstraints(blueView.constraints)
            
            blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            blueView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            blueView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

            blueView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0).isActive = true
            blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0).isActive = true

            
        }

    }

}
```

The issue that I got is Xcode complains about `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:` and i think this complain is about this that I am updating my constraint in wrong way.

The second issue is that redView lose its constraint in process of updating constraint for blueView, which I want redView keeps its constraint to blueView as coded.

The third issue is that it happens without any animation, I want it happens with animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a couple of things. First, you don't attempt to animate anything. Second, you don't need to deactivate any constraints, you simply need to modify them.

In order to modify a constraint, you must do it on that particular constraint instance. And to do this, you may have to expand its scope by making it an instance property of the view controller, which I have done. The constraint can either be optional and `nil` to start, which you can set later, or you can simply declare it on initialization and mark it `lazy`, as I did here, so that it's only read when it's safe to read.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import AppKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    private let blueView = NSView()
    private let redView = NSView()
    
    private lazy var blueViewCenterXAnchor = blueView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 50)
    private lazy var blueViewCenterYAnchor = blueView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 50)
    private lazy var blueViewWidthAnchor = blueView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
    private lazy var blueViewHeightAnchor = blueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = NSView()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        blueView.wantsLayer = true
        blueView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
        blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(blueView)
        blueViewCenterXAnchor.isActive = true
        blueViewCenterYAnchor.isActive = true
        blueViewWidthAnchor.isActive = true
        blueViewHeightAnchor.isActive = true
        
        redView.wantsLayer = true
        redView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
        redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        blueView.addSubview(redView)
        redView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        redView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        redView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        redView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(2)) {
            self.blueViewCenterXAnchor.constant = 0
            self.blueViewCenterYAnchor.constant = 0
            self.blueViewWidthAnchor.constant = 300
            self.blueViewHeightAnchor.constant = 300
            
            NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { context in
                context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
                context.duration = 3
                self.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: There is no window available to see in screen when I run the codes.

Comment: @HelloCodes I edited my answer to include Xcode Playground preview support. Plug that into a Playground. Make sure it's set to macOS and not iOS and that you have Live View enabled.

Comment: thanks, I am coding on Cocoa and on a macOS app and I tried to use new updated code, but i am not seeing the window in screen.

Comment: @HelloCodes get rid of the `override func loadView() { view = NSView() }` in your app. This override is for the Playground.

Comment: Thanks, Is this the only way of animation using `NSAnimationContext ` and `self.view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()`? Do we have other way for this?

Comment: @HelloCodes there are other animation APIs available to you, albeit not many. For simple animations like this, `NSAnimationContext` does the job very well. For more complex animations, including the ability to define animation curves, the other APIs are usually better and sometimes needed. Check this link out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358861/9086770